# Invalid implicit conversion from uint256 to bytes memory requested

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I am trying to create a simple random function but it gives me an error. I can't figure out what I do wrong. Solidity 0.5.0;

```
   function random() private view returns(uint){
        uint source = block.difficulty + now;
        return uint(keccak256(source));
    }
```

> TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid
>   implicit conversion from uint256 to bytes memory requested. This
>   function requires a single bytes argument. Use abi.encodePacked(...)
>   to obtain the pre-0.5.0 behaviour or abi.encode(...) to use ABI
>   encoding.
>           return uint(keccak256(source));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to take the `keccack256` hash of a `uint`, which you cannot do, [according to the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions). What you must do instead is convert the `uint` to a `bytes`.

The code you want is as follows:

```
function random() private returns(uint){
    uint source = block.difficulty + now;
    bytes memory source_b = toBytes(source);
    return uint(keccak256(source_b));
}

function toBytes(uint256 x) public returns (bytes memory b) {
    b = new bytes(32);
    assembly { mstore(add(b, 32), x) }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can make use of abi.encodePacked function

```
 function random() private view returns(uint){
     uint source = block.difficulty + now;
     return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(source)));
   }
```

Comment: This answer should've been marked!

Answer (score 2):

Both of the current answers are excessive

```
function random() private view returns(uint){
    uint source = block.difficulty + now;
    return uint(keccak256(bytes32(source)));
}
```

Also you should not be using block.difficulty or block.timestamp as a source of randomness as they are exploitable by miners. Consider using Chainlink's VRF instead

Comment: The question request a solution for solc 0.5, in that version your code doesn't compile.